# How to proper test threads in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, junit

I am developing an application in Java that uses threads to continuously retrieve data from a website. I would like to use Junit to test them but this is not straightforward. How is it possible to test these threads that do not even have a termination point?

Answer (score 4):

One possiblity is to pull out the work that the threads do into helper methods or classes that can be tested separately in single-threaded unit tests.

Another is to provide mock objects that are invoked by the threads, and can check that the expected behaviour occurs.

Another is to  spawn the worker threads, and get your test to poll something that will tell it whether the threads worked OK (preferably with a timeout so you tests doesn't run forever. The problem here is that your tests can be slow and non-reproducible.

Comment: are there any tools to automate this kind of testing?

Comment: I'm not aware of any beyond JUnit and the various mocking libraries, but it would be worth a look...

Answer (score 2):

why not use jvisualvm (which comes packaged with the jdk 6 and up) to monitor the threads

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/visualvm/threads.html

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear what you mean by ‘test them’. It’s hard for me to see what your thread is – how much functionality is has etc. A classic unit test would test the functions in your class, each on its own. But it seems that is not what you want. I assume you want to test whether many of your threads run in parallel and still do the right thing. This kind of integration test is indeed difficult.

A threaded test is in order here. You have to decide how much of the environment you want to mock – run your tests against the real web site or not. The first may not be viewed friendly by the operators, the latter might introduce errors. I would recommend [TestNG](http://testng.org/doc/index.html) instead of JUnit, as it will easily allow you to run tests in parallel in any number of threads.

Answer (score 0):

Well I think it depends on exactly what you're trying to test.

If you're just trying to test whether or not threads can be spawned, well that's silly - it's baked into the JVM, and isn't going to fail any time soon. (If you have some particular resource condition like low memory that would cause it to fail, I guess that makes sense, but in most I'd say not.)

I would break the test up into two components. Have a test that just does the data retreval, regardless of it is in its own thread or not. Then have your 'black box' test that tells your central component "Go get this data" - it spawns its threads as it feels it needs to.

Comment: I dont want to test if threads are spawned but how they behave under certain conditions, when they fail, when they dont etc...

Comment: But the thread itself is unlikely to fail. Rather, I would test the behaviors the threads are supposed to be performing.

Comment: Since it depends on the website's response, internet connection, and other parameters i would say that there are possibilities of the threads to crash. So the behaviour of the thread is not independent from the thread itself. For example, sometimes i get an illegalstateexception.

Comment: But that's not related to the thread... that's testing the connection and response. You could have that behavior not in a separate thread but still have the same problems to test.